# Travis CI fails to unzip gradle 1.11 with gradle wrapper

Tags: gradle, java-8, travis-ci, gradlew

Since today, the builds of one of my projects fail on Travis CI, because of issues in unzipping gradle 1.11. This applies to newer builds as well as old builds that were executed fine days ago. `gradlew assemble` works fine on my local machine, it only fails on Travis CI. [The output of the build is the following](https://travis-ci.org/lenhard/pete/builds/22676746):

```
Using worker: worker-linux-6-2.bb.travis-ci.org:travis-linux-9

$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=master git://github.com/lenhard/pete.git lenhard/pete
Cloning into 'lenhard/pete'...
remote: Counting objects: 779, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (567/567), done.
remote: Total 779 (delta 325), reused 571 (delta 134)
Receiving objects: 100% (779/779), 4.20 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (325/325), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
$ cd lenhard/pete
$ git checkout -qf 5bef29676d981c7de80517950cbb9b1bb85bba00
$ jdk_switcher use oraclejdk8
Switching to Oracle JDK8 (java-8-oracle), JAVA_HOME will be set to /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for apt.
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b128)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b69, mixed mode)
$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0
before_install
$ chmod +x gradlew
$ ./gradlew assemble
Downloading http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.11-bin.zip

Unzipping /home/travis/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.11-bin/4h5v8877arc3jhuqbm3osbr7o7/gradle-1.11-bin.zip to /home/travis/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.11-bin/4h5v8877arc3jhuqbm3osbr7o7
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:164)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:148)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:65)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:47)
```

Travis tries to repeat `gradlew assemble` two more times, but fails ultimately. My `.travis.yml` is really simple:

```
language: java
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8

before_install:
 - chmod a+x gradlew
```

Where could this issue come from? When accessing `http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.11-bin.zip` from my machine, I get a proper distribution that can be unzipped and works. Could this be related to the fact that I use JDK 1.8?

Comment: Isn't it a permission issue?

Comment: @Opal: I might well be. I just don't know why. The wrapper has executable permissions and this setting was working fine days ago. Do you know of changes in Travis that require me to modify my permission settings?

Comment: No I don't know. I just wonder if Travis has write access to the place where file is downloaded.

Comment: Very good point, I hadn't thought of that! I'll have the wrapper include everything in the project directly and see if that works out.

Comment: Well, now I was getting HTTP 500 when trying to download the gradle binaries for some time. It works again, but I can finally reproduce the error from Travis locally, hooray. There really seem to be issues over at gradle atm. Maybe the best thing would be to give them some time.

Comment: [They have recognized the problem and are working on it](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/gradle_wrapper_does_not_follow_redirects)

Comment: Ok. Nice. Great that You know the cause!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was neither caused by Travis CI, nor by the project configuration. Instead, it seems that the gradle wrapper had problems following redirects for a new host. This came from the enablement of https downloads for the wrapper at gradle.org. The problem was fixed on their side and everything is back to normal now.

[More info on this problem can be found in the gradle forums.](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/gradle_wrapper_does_not_follow_redirects)